# How to retrieve 'Revision Number' of a msi using .NET code?

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I have a msi file. I want to get the Revision Number of this file.

I can get it by properties->summary ({690D33BD-602F-4E71-9CB5-1CF2E9593DEE})

But I want to get this number using .net code.

So can u please help me out in this...

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is called the [Package Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370568(VS.85).aspx).

Here's an example to retrieve using VBscript (unfortunately I'm not familiar with .NET):

```
Dim installer, database

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase ("my.msi", 0)

Dim sumInfo  : Set sumInfo = installer.SummaryInformation("my.msi", 0)
sPackageCode =  sumInfo.Property(9) ' PID_REVNUMBER = 9, contains the package code.

WScript.Echo sPackageCode
```